# Visual Studio 2012 does not hit breakpoint javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm writing a little project in javascript and I'm trying to debug the code.
But when I place a breakpoint in Visual studio 2012 it says `'This breakpoint will not be hit'`. Now the weird thing, the breakpoint stands in the javascript Onloaded function, the one that should be loaded at first. Other array's are already loaded in with values but that is because they are there for a while, now I added a piece of code (to concatenate the array's in one big array), but the chrome javascript console says the array is undefined.

Here is my code, I added the last 2 lines.

```
function onLoaded() {
    defaultPage = document.getElementById('NounVerb');
    tekenwaarde = defaultPage.content.findName('tekenwaarde');
    totalValues = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        totalValues[i] = defaultPage.content.findName('total' + (i + 1));
    }
    nounValues = new Array();
    for (var y = 0; y <= 13; y++) {
        nounValues[y] = defaultPage.content.findName('noun' + (y + 1));
    }
    verbValues = new Array();
    for (var z = 0; z <= 13; z++) {
        verbValues[z] = defaultPage.content.findName('verbs' + (z + 1));
    }
    var allValues = new Array();
    allValues = totalValues.concat(nounValues, verbValues);
}
```

In Internet Explorer these breakpoints are hit, but my design in IE looks all messed up, (that's no problem, this must only work in Chrome), but now I can't test it properly.
Also all my other breakpoints in my functions are not hit, even when I press the button to fire that function.

Is this a problem with Chrome or what else, I really don't know?
Is there anyone who also had this problem?

Regards 
Gijs

Comment: Are you using SilverLight?

Comment: @mhu, yes, downloaded a new version yesterday from the microsoft website

Comment: Where do you set the breakpoints? In VS or in Chrome? If you run Chrome from VS, you still need to debug in Chrome itself (and set breakpoints in the Chrome debugger).

Comment: If you're setting the breakpoints in VS and debugging with Chrome? Then I'm afraid that this won't work. You'll need to set the breakpoints in Chrome and debug from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Chrome from Visual Studio, you still need to debug in Chrome itself (and set breakpoints in the Chrome debugger). You can only step through your javascript in VS if you use Internet Explorer.

The problem with your code is that you didn't declare some of your variables. Consider rewriting the function as follows:

```
function onLoaded() {
    var defaultPage, tekenwaarde, i,
        max = 14,
        totalValues = [], 
        nounValues = [], 
        verbValues = [], 
        allValues = [];

    defaultPage = document.getElementById('NounVerb');
    if (!defaultPage || !defaultPage.content) {
        return;
    }

    tekenwaarde = defaultPage.content.findName('tekenwaarde');
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        totalValues.push(defaultPage.content.findName('total' + i));
        nounValues.push(defaultPage.content.findName('noun' + i));
        verbValues.push(defaultPage.content.findName('verbs' + i));
    }

    allValues = totalValues.concat(nounValues, verbValues);
}
```

Comment: even with that code replacing mine, visual studio does not stop for any breakpoint

Comment: But did this resolve the "array is undefined" error?

Comment: @Gijs. It wont. you can only debug Javascript like that using IE.